# python interpreter, how to stop executing a function while assigning a variable?

Tags: python

```
>>> myvar = print('nothing')
```

Click Enter and the "nothing" is printed in Python console. But I don't want it to be printed, I just want to assign a variable myvar to print function. How do I do this in console?

Comment: This makes no sense as written - if you don't want to print anything, don't use `print()`!  Do you perhaps want `myvar = 'nothing'`?

Answer (score 0):

The question per se makes not much sense, I think what you want is just a function if you do not want to print the value on assignment:

```
def myvar():
  print('nothing')
```

Which you can call to print afterwards with `myvar()`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer then.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @b-fg make a function but you could also do this if you wanted to use a diff name to print, not going to ask your reasons

```
>>> myvar = print
>>> myvar('hello') 
hello
```